# Using node.js in html

Tags: html, node.js, heroku

I already know how to load and host html using node.js. I created a website (only html and css, including some Javascript for frontend) that's frontend is fully finished. I won't be adding any other frontend to it. I need to use node.js server only in one html page, but I'd like to know how I could host all of this on Netlify. Again, I know how I can use localhost and node.js to host an html file: I just don't understand how node.js works and how I can host it on Netlify.

Comment: And note that Stack Overflow isn't meant to replace documentation or tutorials. Search "node.js heroku" or "node.js netlify" with your favourite search engine. You should finde some helpful resources.

Comment: Sorry for this, I'm used to using netlify but I think that you can't host node.js on netlify, sorry for this.

Comment: And have you searched "node.js heroku" like I suggested? What did you find? What have you tried? Again, we're not here to replace search engines, documentation, or tutorials. If you have a _specific_ problem, feel free to come back and search for existing relevant questions and answers. If you can't find any existing ones you can ask a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Node.js is the Runtime environment for javascript. Browers are all run time environments to run javascript along with HTML and CSS. You need to use the server to host your backend code. Use Heroku if you want to host it for free o  buy a Digital ocean server for 5$ per month.

Comment: But how will I set up heroku? Do i just give it my github repo and that's it? How am I going to organize it in order for heroku to know which files to run that are node.js and which files are just javascript that are included in the html?